# JS + PHP $_GET['example'] not working now

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql

So I have made a JS system to load pages, into a default div named PageContent, now I am needed to use the PHP $_GET function and it seems that my JS is making it so the URL variables do not get set.

The Pageload.js 
https://hastebin.com/idazuwovoz.js

The issue is when I add a variable to a URL such as 
example/pages/email?id=10

and then use $_GET['id'] on that page it is blank and saying it is not set, I need to keep the JS as it is a big part of the site and required, but I also need the PHP $_GET to work, can anyone help me solve this issue, please.

Comment: Give us a code sample that demonstrates the issue - and include the javascript side and PHP side.

Comment: I have, the JS is the hastbin link.
The php side is just $_GET['id'];

I can't use that function to get URL variables such as 
example/pages/email?id=10

the issue is that, there is not any more php code than that to share

Comment: Maybe I'm just tired but I don't see anywhere you are passing query string parameters in the code you displayed. Where are you passing "?id=10" in the code linked above?

Comment: https://hastebin.com/idazuwovoz.js

I just updated the hastbin to show more info, hope it helps, sorry I am bad at asking for help I always assume everyone else knows my project haha

Comment: I am bowing out then. Again, maybe it's because I'm tired. But no where in that code is "?id=10" or any other query string parameter added AFTER the ".php" part. I only see code that would end up making requests like "/inc/pages/<somepage?id=10>.php". Again, I am tired and may still be missing the problem. Replace the .load with alert statements and see what URL you are actually calling.

Answer (score 0):

Try including

let newUrl='inc/pages' +url+'.php';
alert(newUrl) ;

after one of your url.replace lines to see the actual url you are getting